# Grab all rows in a table and grab one row where condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an integer column that's set to 1 for nearly all rows in my table, 2 for about 10 rows, and 3 for 6 rows. I want a to select all rows from my table where that column is not equal to 3, but grab the most recently updated row where it is equal to 3. I also have an updated_at column that is a date column.

Here is the sql I've come up with so far.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM mytable 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
               FROM mytable 
              WHERE spec_id=3 
              ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 1) mytable2 
         ON mytable.id=mytable2.id
```

However, this statement grabs all 6 of my rows where spec_id is set to 3.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `union all`

```
(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE spec_id=3 ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE spec_id!=3
```

Comment: Oh nevermind. I was missing the parenthesis. Now I'm getting this error: `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "mytable"`

Comment: @Michael I was writing about  considering parentheses :)

Comment: Ok, I guess I needed parenthesis around the second select query.

Comment: @Michael No, not needed for the one (the second) without `order by`.

Comment: Oh I see. I was trying to use `order by` on the second select as well.